# Why is it needed that the ItemsSource is a list?

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I have a tree view in my xaml file like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,0,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Descendants}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Node.Name}}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

My view model has this property:

```
private List<NodeViewModel> _items = new List<NodeViewModel>();
public List<NodeViewModel> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Items");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I I have noticed that the list items has always only one element, the root item, and the tree is created by iterating through the descendants. So I try to change the property to this:

```
private NodeViewModel _rootItem;
public List<NodeViewModel> RootItem
{
    get { return _rootItem; }
    set
    {
        _rootItem= value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("RootItem");
    }
}
```

But in this way the tree is not showed.

So, the itemsSource of the tree view must be a list? Why if I always have only one element in the list, that is the root item?

Comment: The `ItemsSource` of the TreeView must be an `IEnumerable` simply because a `TreeView` is an `ItemsControl` and it behaves like any other `ItemsControl` in how it deals with it's `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction: it's not necessary it to be `List`, but `IEnumerable`.

The reason is quite simple:`TreeView` can have more than 1 element as "root". If you'd like to do it this way, as you've done, you can create a `Converter` that will convert `NodeViewModel` into `List<NodeViewModel>`.